# What does "floated out" mean?

Tags: haskell

On the [Haskell wiki I read that this](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Let_vs._Where#Problems_with_where):

```
fib =
    let fib' 0 = 0
        fib' 1 = 1
        fib' n = fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2)
    in  (map fib' [0 ..] !!)
```

is more efficient than this:

```
 fib x =
    let fib' 0 = 0
        fib' 1 = 1
        fib' n = fib (n - 1) + fib (n - 2)
    in  map fib' [0 ..] !! x
```

Because, *"In the second case fib' is (re-)defined for every argument x, thus it cannot be floated out."*

I don't understand what this means.

1. **What does "floated out" mean? How is it an optimization?**
2. Why is `fib'` being redefined for each invocation of `fib`?
3. Is this an eta-expansion or not?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's not a very good explanation.

"Floated out" simply means that in:

```
\x -> let y = ... in z
```

if `...` does not mention *x* then it can be *floated out* of the lambda:

```
let y = ... in \x -> z
```

which means it will only be computed once,<sup>1</sup> which could save a lot of time if `...` is expensive. However, GHC is conservative about performing optimisations like this, since they can introduce space leaks. (Though it *does* do so for the second definition if you give it a type signature, as Daniel Fischer points out in his answer.)

This isn't about automatic optimisation, though. The first snippet defines `fib'` outside of the lambda, whereas the second defines it inside (the lambda is implicit in `fib x = ...`, which is equivalent to `fib = \x -> ...`), which is what the quote is saying.

Even that's not really relevant, however; what's relevant is that in the first snippet, `map fib' [0 ..]` occurs outside the lambda, and so its result is shared among all applications of the lambda (in that code, the "lambda" arises from the partial application of `(!!)`). In the latter, it's inside the lambda, and so likely to be recomputed for every application of `fib`.

The end result is that the former implementation caches the values and so is far more efficient than the latter. Note that the first snippet's efficiency is dependent on the fact that `fib'` doesn't recurse directly, but instead through `fib`, and therefore benefits from the memoisation.

It's related to eta-expansion; the latter snippet is an eta-expansion of the first. But the statement you quoted doesn't explain what's going on at all.

<sup>1</sup> Note that this is implementation-specific behaviour, and not part of Haskell's semantics. However, all reasonable implementations will behave in this manner.

Comment: This answer and Daniel Fischer's answer are now mutually recursive.

Comment: @misterbee: luckily, only Haskell programmers will read them, and we're lazy, right?

Answer (score 13):

**ehird**'s answer explains things very well, however there's one point

> The end result is that the former implementation caches the values and so is far more efficient than the latter.

that is sometimes wrong.

If you compile the module containing either definition with optimisations (I checked only -O2, not -O1, and of course only GHC), there are several cases to consider:

1. the first definition without type signature
2. the second definition with type signature `fib :: Int -> Integer`
3. the first definition with polymorphic type `fib :: Num a => Int -> a`
4. the second definition without type signature
5. the second definition with type signature `fib :: Num a => Int -> a`

In case 1, the monomorphism restriction produces the type `fib :: Int -> Integer` and the list `map fib' [0 .. ]` is shared across all invocations of `fib`. That means if you ever query `fib (10^6)`, you have a list of the first million (+1) Fibonacci numbers in memory, and it will be collected only when the garbage collector can determine it's no longer used. That's often a memory leak.

In case 2, the result(ing core) is practically identical to case 1.

In case 4, the list isn't shared across different top-level invocations of `fib` (of course; the result can have many types, so there'd be many lists to share), but it's instantiated once per top-level invocation and reused for the calls from `fib'`, so calculating `fib n` requires O(n) additions and O(n^2) steps through the list. That's not too bad. The list is collected when the calculation is complete, so no space leak.

Case 3 is practically identical to 4.

Case 5, however, is worse than the naive recursion. Since it's explicitly polymorphic and the list is bound inside the lambda, the list cannot be reused for the recursive calls, each recursive call creates a new list ...

Comment: Hmm, so GHC *does* float the list out of the second definition when monomorphic? Cool, I didn't realise it could do that.

Comment: GHC is pretty awesome. And it gets better and better :)