# How lazy is Haskell's `++`?

Tags: string, optimization, haskell, lazy-evaluation

I'm curious how I should go about improving the performance of a Haskell routine that finds the lexicographically minimal cyclic rotation of a string.

```
import Data.List
swapAt n = f . splitAt n where f (a,b) = b++a
minimumrotation x = minimum $ map (\i -> swapAt i x) $ elemIndices (minimum x) x
```

I'd imagine that I should use Data.Vector rather than lists because Data.Vector provides in-place operations, probably just manipulating some indices into the original data.  I shouldn't actually need to bother tracking the indices myself to avoid excess copying, right?

I'm curious how the `++` impact the optimization though.  I'd imagine it produces a lazy string thunk that never does the appending until the string gets read that far.  Ergo, the `a` should never actually be appended onto the `b` whenever minimum can eliminate that string early, like because it begins with some very later letter.  Is this correct?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Clearly you've never seen the Haskell programs in the [benchmarks game](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u64q/haskell.php)!

Comment: My humourous and well-intentioned comment got deleted. :( Go figure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`xs ++ ys` adds some overhead in all the list cells from `xs`, but once it reaches the end of `xs` it's free — it just returns `ys`.

Looking at the definition of `(++)` helps to see why:

```
[] ++ ys = ys
(x:xs) ++ ys = x : (xs ++ ys)
```

i.e., it has to "re-build" the entire first list as the result is traversed. [This article](http://apfelmus.nfshost.com/articles/debit-method.html) is very helpful for understanding how to reason about lazy code in this way.

The key thing to realise is that appending isn't done all at once; a new linked list is incrementally built by first walking through all of `xs`, and then putting `ys` where the `[]` would go.

So, you don't have to worry about reaching the end of `b` and suddenly incurring the one-time cost of "appending" `a` to it; the cost is spread out over all the elements of `b`.

Vectors are a different matter entirely; they're strict in their structure, so even examining just the first element of `xs V.++ ys` incurs the entire overhead of allocating a new vector and copying `xs` and `ys` to it — just like in a strict language. The same applies to mutable vectors (except that the cost is incurred when you perform the operation, rather than when you force the resulting vector), although I think you'd have to write your own append operation with those anyway. You could represent a bunch of appended (immutable) vectors as `[Vector a]` or similar if this is a problem for you, but that just moves the overhead to when you flattening it back into a single Vector, and it sounds like you're more interested in mutable vectors.

Comment: Fine, but presumably switching to `Data.Vector` fixes this, yes?  Or does it create a separate copy penalty?  In that case, I should simply create my own `twovectors` type or something?

Comment: @JeffBurdges: I've expanded my answer to cover Vectors :)

Comment: Thanks!  Another small question :  If I wrote `minimumrotation x = minimum $ map f $ elemIndices (minimum x) x where f i = take (length x) $ drop i (x++x)`.  Are the `length x` and `x++x` evaluated only once when `f` is dethunked?

Comment: @JeffBurdges: Maybe, but I [wouldn't count on it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779390/what-does-floated-out-mean); GHC is conservative about that kind of optimisation. You should probably give `length x` a name (in the same where block as `f`'s definition); I wouldn't worry about the `(x++x)` part. (Note that `f` itself is already in weak-head normal form, and so never gets forced ("dethunked"); it's `f i` that will get forced, for varying values of `i`.)

Comment: I'm curious if strict apply `$!` might fix that without creating new labels, any idea?

Comment: @JeffBurdges: That won't help; you have to lift the expression outside of the lambda-expression.

Comment: Ahh alright, thanks again!  I'll keep this in mind when making such local functions in future.

Comment: @JeffBurdges: Note that it applies just as much to top-level functions too; transforming `foo x = ... where expensive = <expr not mentioning x>` into `foo = \x -> ... where expensive = <expr not mentioning x>` could have a large effect :) Of course, you should profile before making such changes, since it's entirely possible GHC will be optimising it away...

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
minimumrotation :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
minimumrotation xs = minimum . take len . map (take len) $ tails (cycle xs)
  where
    len = length xs
```

I expect that to be faster than what you have, though index-juggling on an unboxed `Vector` or `UArray` would probably be still faster. But, is it really a bottleneck?

Comment: Is cycle faster than `xs++xs`?  I'd assume yes a priori.  Am I correct that swapping the two `take`s shouldn't impact performance since all those thunks must be computed anyways?

Comment: `cycle xs` is just `fix (xs ++)`, so if anything `xs ++ xs` will be cheaper, but I wouldn't worry about it; the overhead will be minuscule. Swapping the `take len` and `map (take len)` will have no effect.

Comment: If there's any performance difference between `xs ++ xs` and `cycle xs` here, I would be surprised if it wasn't minuscule. I don't think swapping `take len` and `map (take len)` would make a measurable difference, but I haven't benchmarked it.

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested in fast concatenation and a fast `splitAt`, use [Data.Sequence](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Sequence.html).

I've made some stylistic modifications to your code, to make it look more like idiomatic Haskell, but the logic is exactly the same, except for a few conversions to and from `Seq`:

```
import qualified Data.Sequence as S
import qualified Data.Foldable as F

minimumRotation :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]
minimumRotation xs = F.toList
                   . F.minimum
                   . fmap (`swapAt` xs')
                   . S.elemIndicesL (F.minimum xs')
                   $ xs'
  where xs' = S.fromList xs
        swapAt n = f . S.splitAt n
          where f (a,b) = b S.>< a
```

Comment: Ahh, several slick tricks there, including the infix `swapAt`. lol

Comment: @JeffBurdges - another option is `(flip swapAt xs')`, but I personally prefer the infix section.

Comment: Naturally it would be best to use sequences all the way through so that `toList` and `fromList` don't take up a lot of time for the program