# Caching possible values of a function constructed at runtime

Tags: performance, caching, haskell, lazy-evaluation

I have a data constructor with a few value constructors:

```
data DataType = C1 | C2 | C3 | ... | Cn
```

I'd like to build a function at run time from that data type to some other values (in fact, I'm doing this in an IO monad):

```
buildFun :: IO (DataType -> b)
buildFun = do
    ....
    return $ \x -> case x of
                       C1 -> someProcessesToGetTheValue C1
                       ...
                       Cn -> someProcessesToGetTheValue Cn
```

Will this mean that someProcessesToGetTheValue will be called each time I call the returned function?

I'd prefer Haskell to evaluate someProcessesToGetTheValue inside buildFun (since those calls are quite expensive) and return a function which returns these fully evaluated expressions.

Can I force that behaviour? Perhaps by doing something like the following?:

```
buildFun :: IO (DataType -> b)
buildFun = do
    C1value <- return $ someProcessesToGetTheValue C1
    ...
    Cnvalue <- return $ someProcessesToGetTheValue Cn
    return $ \x -> case x of
                       C1 -> C1value
                       ...
                       Cn -> Cnvalue
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to involve the IO monad at all (and indeed `do { x <- return v; ... }` is identical to `let x = v in ...`), just bind the values outside the lambda:

```
buildFun :: IO (DataType -> b)
buildFun = do
    let v1 = someProcessesToGetTheValue C1
    ...
    return $ \x -> case x of { C1 -> v1; ... }
```

Haskell doesn't really specify anything about runtime evaluation behaviour, but on all common implementations this will ensure that the results are *shared*; see [What does "floated out" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8779390/what-does-floated-out-mean) for more information.

However, it still won't evaluate *v*<sub>1</sub>…*v*<sub>*n*</sub> inside `buildFun`; instead, they will each be evaluated the first time the corresponding result of the function you return is evaluated. If you want to force them to be evaluated up-front, you can say `let !v1 = someProcessesToGetTheValue C1` (this requires the `BangPatterns` language extension), or `v1 <- evaluate $ someProcessesToGetTheValue C1` (from `Control.Exception`; this behaves better if `someProcessesToGetTheValue C1` might throw an exception).

Comment: Cool. I'm in the IO monad for a different reason, but I might factor that out. Thanks!

Comment: Right, I just meant that you don't need to use it directly to achieve this caching behaviour. (In case you didn't see, I expanded my answer since you posted your first comment.)

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't read carefully enough. In this case someProcesses... is actually also taking some arguments from the IO, but I see your point. Thanks for your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a function, why not instead define some data structure, like a list, of all the the results of evaluating this function (indexed by position of constructor in data type)? For example, something like this (not tested):

```
data DataType = C1 | C2 | C3 | ... | Cn deriving (Enum, Bounded)

cachedValues :: [b]
cachedValues = map someProcessesToGetTheValue ([minBound .. maxBound] :: [DataType])

getCachedValue :: DataType -> b
getCachedValue x = cachedValues !! (fromEnum x)
```

Since Haskell is lazy, it will store a thunk until it is run for the first time, after which it will remember the value.

(If list traversal over the list of size n is inefficient; you can use an array or `Map` instead. The idea is the same.)